# django PasswordChangeView always redirect to login

Tags: django

i use django PasswordChangeView to change password, but the url always redirect to login view , can anybody help me?

in views.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
class PasswordChangeView(auth_views.PasswordChangeView):
    template_name = 'accounts/registration/password_change_form.html'
```

in urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('logout/', views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    path('password_change/', views.PasswordChangeView.as_view() , name='password_change'),
]
```

but when i goto password_change url, it redirect to login ???

```
[18/Jul/2018 13:17:53] "GET /accounts/password_change/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[18/Jul/2018 13:17:53] "GET /accounts/login/?next=/accounts/password_change/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4772
```

Comment: If you want to change password before login, use `PasswordResetView`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When user change password, the auth session expire so automatically logged out and redirect to login page.

For prevent this, you can use `get_session_auth_hash()`.

Example below.

```
from django.contrib.auth import update_session_auth_hash

def password_change(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PasswordChangeForm(user=request.user, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            update_session_auth_hash(request, form.user)
    else:
        ...
```

You can see more detail in [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#session-invalidation-on-password-change)